# Unicode HTTP Host: Header Field?

Tags: http, unicode, utf-8, http-headers, packet-capture

What does the `Host:` header look like for a Unicode domain. e.g. æon.com in the MOST STANDARD format (assuming RFC 5987? or is it something else?)?

I am developing a transparent proxy that will need to work across different browsers and languages.

Could you paste an example of a `Host: æon.com` HTTP header, same as a Wireshark Packet Dump would produce, un-decoded and specifically the `Host:` field.

Comment: Thanks for the answers the the Host: value is expressed in "xn--" notation. Does anyone have the RFC citation that specifies this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

International domain names are encoded in [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). "æon.com" [is represented by](http://www.freesitemapgenerator.com/idn-to-punycode.html) "xn--on-0ia.com".

Answer (score 2):

a) RFC 5987 is only applicable to certain header field parameters, not entire header fields.

b) The host header field should be whatever the host name in the HTTP URI (!!!, not IRI), was (as explained by deceze, puny-coded).